# Recoded missing cells to NA but still showing up in table

Tags: dplyr, gtsummary

I'm trying to build a table using gtsummary.  I"m converting columns to factors, then recoding the factors, then assigning values (" ", "U") to be missing.

However, when I then make the table, the levels that are assigned "missing" still show up as levels in the table.  How do I get them to be hidden?

```
data <- tribble(
  ~Patient, ~malig, ~donor,
  #---------/-------/------
  "Peter", "Y", "DCD",
  "Bob", "N", "DBD",
  "John", "U", "DCD",
  "Kate", " ", "DBD"
)

names<-c('malig','donor')

data[,names]<-lapply(data[,names], factor)

data$malig<-recode_factor(data$malig, 
                              "N"="No", 
                              "Y"="Yes")

data <- data %>% 
  mutate_all(na_if,"") %>%
  mutate_all(na_if,"U") %>%
  mutate_all(na_if," ")

(table1 <- 
  tbl_summary(
    data,
    by = donor, 
    missing="no", 
    label=list(malig ~ "Malignancy History")
  ) %>%
  add_n() %>% 
  add_p() %>% 
  modify_header() %>% 
  add_overall())
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example, one we can all run on our machines? Then we can help diagnose the issue

Comment: Edited to add reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tbl_summary()` function will report all levels of a factor variable, even if they are unobserved. If you don't want to report the unobserved levels, you need to remove the unobserved levels from the factor levels. In this example, you can make the values NA before you make the columns factors.

Comment: That did it!  Thank you - and thanks for this package.  It's incredible.